# Moment.js moment().local() doesn't return my local time

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

### Introduction

I am currently in Spain and my UTC offset is +1 hours. I have seen there is a method in moment.js that converts a given date to a local date... [Click here to see this method in the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/)

### CODE

I am doing this:

```
const relativeToUserDate = moment().local();
```

### Problem

And when I console log this I am not getting my local time.

```
console.log(relativeToUserDate.locale()) // "en"
console.log(relativeToUserDate) // "2020-09-02T16:28:06.550Z" -- My real local time is: 2020-09-02T18:28:06.550Z
```

What am I doing wrong? I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Should work, what is your time zone at your pc?

Comment: Bruselles, Madrid (The correct UTC)

Comment: Are you using moment-timezone?

Comment: I got Wed Sep 02 2020 18:37:48 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit) But with the "_isUTC: false" it's looks like you just got the UTC time. Is "_isUTC" on true?

Comment: @CoryDanielson no.

Comment: @Silvan was your correct date?

Comment: The final `console.log` outputs an object. You should convert to string with `relativeToUserDate.format()`.

Comment: @trincot now is working perfect! Thanks man! Also, if I do realativeToUserDate.toDate() will I get the localtime as a Date object or the wrong date?

Comment: Again, the same principle: `toDate` returns an object. You need to call the appropriate method on that object to turn it into a string representation. For instance, `toLocaleString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final `console.log` outputs an object. You should convert to string with

```
relativeToUserDate.format()
```

If you get `.toDate()` you'll get the current date/time also. Note that internally JavaScript stores dates as UTC, and it uses your locale to determine how to display it with methods like `toLocaleString`. You should always use methods on these date objects to tell it what exactly you want. Don't output the objects as-is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `local` method is used to convert a UTC date to a local date, what does `moment().format()` give you? pretty sure `moment()` should already use your local time.